# SQL Server : taking values doubling it and inserting into new column 20x

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I in a single statement update multiple columns, multiplying the original value for each time based on column updating in Microsoft SQL Server?

Example of table data:

[image: Database Structure]

So `Value_1` and `Value_Off_1` need to be doubled and inserted into `Value_2` and `Value_Off_2`,  and so on and so on for each value:

So for an example:

- `Value_1 = 2` would become `Value_2 = 4`, and `Value_3 = 6` and `Value_4 = 8`
  `Value_Off_1 = 12` would become `Value_Off_2 = 24` and `Value_Off_3 = 36`

This would go all way up to value_20

Basically its a Value multiples by the the Column Number if that makes it any easier

Comment: Can I take a step back and ask what this is going to be used for? Because if literally implemented like this, you're storing a whole bunch of data redundantly, which is a cardinal sin in database design. Will the values later be changed so they're no longer duplicates, or is this pure redundancy for a later calculation (which might be better served by a table-valued function or by joining with a numbers table)?

Comment: Sample data (as DDL and DML statements)  expected results (as formatted `text`) and your attempts will greatly help us help you here. What you're asking is quite unclear and an image of data doesn't aid us in helping you when it dosen't have the full dataset (and you expect some poor soul to transcribe the whole thing; which you should not).

Answer (score 2):

In a Update query you can specify the new value with the value of another column. So the query you want may be like this

```sql
    UPDATE table SET Value_2 = Value_1 * 2, Value_Off_2 = Value_Off_1 * 2, Value_3 = Value_1 * 3, Value_Off_3 = Value_Off_1 * 3 ....
```

Where table is your table name.

Comment: This would work and this is what i was typing up, Adding a Value for each Column, I was wondering if there was a more recursive / loop that could be achieved based on the column name.

Comment: @DaveHamilton: this is a classic case of something that's probably better served by storing your data in rows, rather than columns. If each row had a column for the number, multiplying by that would be trivial.